# Average every several rows in a big numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, average

Let's say I have an array with the shape `(100000000, 4)`. 
I would like to calculate the `mean(axis=0)` every 25 rows to get a new array with the shape `(4000000, 4)`.

To be more clear, the following is a simple example:
A 4 by 4 array `H` is shown. I would like to calculate the `mean(axis=0)` every 2 rows to get a new array `J` with the shape `(2, 4)`.

```py
H = [[1,1,1,1],
     [2,2,2,2],
     [3,3,3,3],
     [4,4,4,4]]

J = [[1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5],
     [3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5]]
```

I was wondering if there is an efficient way to do it without using for loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume first dimension is (exactly) divisible by `m`. Then you could do this:

```
J = H.reshape((H.shape[0] // m, m, H.shape[1])).mean(axis=1)
```

or, even simpler, let `numpy` figure out the size of the first dimension:

```
J = H.reshape((-1, m, H.shape[1])).mean(axis=1)
```

For your specific example `m=2`:

```
In [3]: m = 2
   ...: J = H.reshape((H.shape[0]//m, m, H.shape[1])).mean(axis=1)
   ...: print(J)
[[1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5]
 [3.5 3.5 3.5 3.5]]
```